# How do I properly setup multiple sites locally with apache vhost?

Tags: magento-2.1

Locally I have setup two themes.

```
Theme Directories
app/design/frontend/VendorParent/default   //Inherits from Luma
app/design/frontend/VendorChild/default    //Inherits from VendorParent
```

On the admin side under Content -> Configuration, I have two websites setup.

```
Main Website      //Uses VendorParent theme
Another Website   //User VendorChild theme
```

Under my etc/hosts file I have added entries for both of these sites. I have also added these to the apache vhost file and pointed them both to the same location (magento folder)

```
127.0.0.1 mainsite.magento.dev
127.0.0.1 anothersite.magento.dev
```

I went under stores -> configuration -> general -> web. Here I turned off the 'Auto-redirect to Base URL' option for the default site. Then I went into the same place for the anothersite and changed the 'Base URL' and 'Base Link URL' to be anothersite.magento.dev (I also did this for secure urls here).

I can hit both urls properly, however when I go to anothersite.magento.dev, it is trying to load css files for the mainsite.magento.dev, and I am getting a bunch of font CORS errors in the console. here are the paths it is trying to load for the css.

```
mainsite.magento.com/pub/static/version1498747501/frontend/Main/default/en_US/mage
mainsite.magento.com/pub/static/version1498747501/frontend/Main/default/en_US/css
mainsite.magento.com/pub/static/version1498747501/frontend/Main/default/en_US/Main/css
mainsite.magento.com/pub/static/version1498747501/frontend/Main/default/en_US/css
mainsite.magento.com/pub/media
mainsite.magento.com/pub/static/version1498747501/frontend/Main/default/en_US/css
```

And here are the font CORS error paths.

```
Access to Font at 'http://mainsite.magento.dev/pub/static/version1498747501/frontend/Main/default/en_US/fonts/Blank-Theme-Icons/Blank-Theme-Icons.woff2' from origin 'http://anothersite.magento.dev' has been blocked by CORS policy
Access to Font at 'http://mainsite.magento.dev/pub/static/version1498747501/frontend/Main/default/en_US/fonts/Another/Another-Regular.woff' from origin 'http://anothersite.magento.dev' has been blocked by CORS policy:
Access to Font at 'http://mainsite.magento.dev/pub/static/version1498747501/frontend/Main/default/en_US/fonts/Blank-Theme-Icons/Blank-Theme-Icons.woff' from origin 'http://anothersite.magento.dev' has been blocked by CORS policy:
Access to Font at 'http://mainsite.magento.dev/pub/static/version1498747501/frontend/Main/default/en_US/fonts/Another/Another-Regular.ttf' from origin 'http://anothersite.magento.dev' has been blocked by CORS policy:
```

Actually now that I look at it, it is using the mainsite url for all assets being loaded on the anothersite url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I missed the section in the setup where I needed to add the     SetEnv to my apache vhost file. After adding this it works! The reference is [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_apache.html).

```
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "german"
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "website"
```